# How can I tell the website administration tool which provider to use?

Tags: asp.net

I have this membership provider, and I'm using the "website administration tool" launched from Visual Studio->PROJECT->ASP.NET Configuration.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <add connectionStringName="DefaultConnection" enablePasswordRetrieval="false"
      enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false"
      requiresUniqueEmail="true"
      maxInvalidPasswordAttempts="5"
      minRequiredPasswordLength="6"
      minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"
      passwordAttemptWindow="10"
      applicationName="/" name="DefaultMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Providers.DefaultMembershipProvider, System.Web.Providers, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </providers>
</membership>
```

Changing these `minRequiredPasswordLength="6"`, `minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0"` has no effect so I suspect it's not using that provider.

Adding `<clear/>` before the add only makes it worse and proves it's getting it elsewhere.

```
<membership>
  <providers>
    <clear/>
    <add....
```

This leads to this message on the page `http://localhost:58144/asp.netwebadminfiles/security/security0.aspx`:

> The following message may help in diagnosing the problem: Default Membership Provider could not be found.

So how can I tell it to use that provider, or how can I configure the provider to what it expects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I must give it a default provider here:

```
<membership defaultProvider="DefaultMembershipProvider">
```